# How do i add redis to selinux so that it's permissive?

Tags: centos, selinux, redis

I'm new to SELinux and CentOS, I have two vm's running a minimal centos7, I've configured firewall-cmd for the default redis port, but the only way I've been able to get the two vm's allowing redis to master/slave is by doing setenforce 0.

I can see that `redis_port_t` and `redis_t` are known to SELinux but what do I need to do next to add a policy to SELinux to allow access to redis. In particular the service aspect as if I nmap from the host to the vm's I can see ssh is available as a service.

Comment: I find it particularly strange that if you have `iptables` allowing connections to `6379` for SELinux to reject it.  Still if you could post the result of `semanage port -l` that will give good info about what SELinux is doing.

Comment: Well strange as it may be, that exactly the situation I'm in. If I stop firewalld I still can't access port 6379, unless I put selinux into permissive mode.